# $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, alternative-proof

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

My working:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx=-\sum_{r\ge 1}\int_0^{1}x^{2r}\ln x\,dx =\sum_{r\ge 1}\frac {1}{(2r-1)^2}= 
\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

Is there any other approach?

Comment: See the answers to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537903/improper-integral-int-limits-01-frac-lnxx2-1-dx

Comment: \begin{align}\int_1^{\infty}x^{2r}\ln x\,dx\end{align} doesn't converge for $r\geq 0$ integer.

Comment: You have to perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$ before to use series expansion.

Comment: ... and performing the change of variables advised by @FDP, you will see that your integral is the same as $\int_0^1 \frac{log(x)}{x^2-1}$...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improper Integral $\int\limits_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-1}\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537903/improper-integral-int-limits-01-frac-lnxx2-1-dx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide *two* different methods. The first relies on properties of the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function), the second converts the integral to a double integral first before evaluating it.

Let
$$I = \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2 - 1} \, dx.$$

---

**Method 1** - *A polygamma approach*

By enforcing a substitution of $x \mapsto 1/x$ we see that
$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2 - 1} \, dx.$$

From the following [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations) for the *digamma function* $\psi (x)$, namely 
$$\psi (x + 1) = -\gamma + \int_0^1 \frac{1 - t^x}{1 - t} \, dt,$$
where $\gamma$ is the *Euler–Mascheroni constant*, on differentiating with respect to $x$ we have
$$\psi^{(1)} (x + 1) = - \int_0^1 \frac{t^x \ln t}{1 - t} \, dt.$$
Here $\psi^{(1)} (z)$ denotes the *trigamma function*. Substituting $t = u^2$, $dt = 2u \, du$ on finds
$$\psi^{(1)} (x + 1) = 4 \int_0^1 \frac{u^{2x + 1} \ln u}{u^2 - 1} \, du.$$
Setting $x = -1/2$ then yields
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2 - 1} \, dx = \frac{1}{4} \psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ).$$
Here the dummy variable $u$ has been reverted back to $x$.

To find the value for the trigamma function at $x = 1/2$ we note that for the polygamma function one has (see Eq. (16) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html))
$$\psi^{(n)} \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ) = (-1)^{n + 1} n! (2^{n + 1} - 1) \zeta (n + 1).$$
Here $\zeta (z)$ denotes the *Riemann zeta function*. Setting $n = 1$ yields
$$\psi^{(1)} \left (\frac{1}{2} \right ) = 3 \cdot \zeta (2) = 3 \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{6} = \frac{\pi^2}{2}.$$
Thus
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2 - 1} \, dx = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}.$$

---

**Method 2** - *Using a double integral*

The problem the first method suffers from is its heavy reliance on a knowledge of the polygamma function. In this second approach, knowing any properties for the polygamma and zeta functions are completely avoided altogether.

Note that as
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2 - 1} \, dx =  \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2 - 1} \, dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2 - 1} \, dx,$$
we have
$$I = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2 - 1} \, dx = \frac{1}{4} \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln (x^2)}{x^2 - 1} \, dx. \tag1$$
Observing that
$$\ln (x^2) = \int_0^\infty \left (\frac{x^2}{1 + x^2 t} - \frac{1}{1 + t} \right ) \, dt,$$
we can rewrite (1) as
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \left (\frac{x^2}{1 + x^2 t} - \frac{1}{1 + t} \right ) \frac{1}{x^2 - 1} \, dt \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1 + t} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1 + x^2 t} \, dx \, dt,
\end{align}
after the order of integration has been changed. Evaluating we have
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{4} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{t} (1 + t)} \big{[} \tan^{-1} (x \sqrt{t}) \big{]}_0^\infty \, dt\\
&= \frac{\pi}{8} \int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t} (1 + t)}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \int_0^\infty \frac{dy}{1 + y^2} \qquad \text{(let $t = y^2$)}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \big{[} \tan^{-1} y \big{]}_0^\infty\\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{8},
\end{align}
as expected.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}J&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2x\ln(x^2)}{1-x^2}dx-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx\\
\end{align}

In the first integral perform the change of variable $y=x^2$,

\begin{align}J&=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx\\
&=-\frac{3}{4}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx\\
&=-\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2)\\
&=-\frac{3}{4}\times -\frac{\pi^2}{6}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{8}\\
\end{align}

NB:

I assume that,
\begin{align} \zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\\
\end{align}

And,

\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx&=\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)\ln x\,dx\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_{0}^{1}x^n\ln x\,dx\\
&-=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\\
&=-\zeta(2)
\end{align}

For $0\leq x<1$,

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{x}{1-x^2}-\frac{1}{1-x}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

The substitution $x\mapsto\coth(x)$ works out quite well. From hereon we get

$$-\int_1^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{1-x^2}\mathrm dx=\int_\infty^0\log(\coth(x))\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty\log(\coth(x))\mathrm dx$$

Since the hyperbolic cotangent is defined in terms of exponentials we may further rewrite this whole as

\begin{align*}
&\int_0^\infty\log(\coth(x))\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty\log\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}\right)\mathrm dx = \int_0^\infty\log\left(\frac{1+e^{-2x}}{1-e^{-2x}}\right)\mathrm dx\\
=&\int_0^\infty\log\left(1+e^{-2x}\right)-\log\left(1-e^{-2x}\right)\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{e^{-2nx}}{n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{-2nx}}{n}\mathrm dx
\end{align*}

Due the monotone dominate convergence theorem we are allowed to switch the order of integration and summation and integration which further gives us

\begin{align*}
&\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{e^{-2nx}}{n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{-2nx}}{n}\mathrm dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2nx}}{n}\mathrm dx+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-2nx}}{n}\mathrm dx\\
=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\left[-\frac{e^{-2nx}}{2n}\right]_0^\infty+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[-\frac{e^{-2nx}}{2n}\right]_0^\infty=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n^2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2n^2}=\frac12[\eta(2)+\zeta(2)]\\
=&\frac12\left[\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{\pi^2}6\right]=\frac12\left[\frac{\pi^2}4\right]=\frac{\pi^2}8
\end{align*}

> $$\therefore~\int_1^\infty\frac{\log(x)}{x^2-1}\mathrm dx~=~\int_0^\infty\log(\coth(x))\mathrm dx~=~\frac{\pi^2}8$$

$\zeta(s)$ and $\eta(s)$ are the Riemman Zeta Function and the Dirichlet Eta Function respectively. Their series definitions and the relation $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$ were used aswell as the well-known value of $\zeta(2)$. Please ask if something is unclear. Overall it is just another way of gaining the series representation of your integral.

Basically it is the same question as here: [Integral of $\ln(\tanh(x))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027576/integral-of-ln-tanhx) since you get your value by multiplying the expression by minus one due the relation between the hyperbolic tangent and cotagent function.

Comment: You assume the values of $\zeta(2)$ AND $\eta(2)$

Comment: @FDP I should add the rather simple, and easy provable relation, $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$ from where one can deduce $\eta(2)$. Of course, right now I am assuming $\zeta(2)$ *and* $\eta(2)$.